# GFCI that opens when power source cut

Tags: gfci

Usually when the source of power in GFCIs were cut, the switching contacts remain shorted.

What kind of GFCIs can open the switching contacts when there is loss of power source?

This is useful for open service neutral faults detection/disconection, where the GFCI would disable the output when it happens.

Comment: If there is no power why are you concerned?

Comment: With normal GFCI. If the neutral is cut. The switching contacts don't open. so if you will use these as open service neutral detector. The moment the neutral is cut, then all contacts open, so you don't have the current diverting (instead to neutral) to the neutral/ground bond and to all the metal chassis. See: https://www.mikeholt.com/mojonewsarchive/NEC-HTML/HTML/DangerofOpenServiceNeutral~20020816.htm

Comment: That is an old article I know the gfci outlets I use on my portable power station if power is cut the gfci opens and has to be reset. But if there is more than 5 ma of imbalance power going other than to the load ie a ground fault on the neutral the gfci trips out, with modern GFCI'S I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

### This is found on plug-in GFCIs

The behavior you are describing is found on GFCIs that are intended to be *plugged into a receptacle*, like the one depicted below, instead of hardwired into building wiring.  It is necessary to prevent the combination of an open neutral in the building wiring and a ground fault in the appliance from causing a shock hazard the GFCI cannot cut off (because it has no power to its electronics in that case).

[image: cord-and-plug GFCI] [image: wall-plug GFCI]

Comment: Why is the feature not available in GFCI receptables or GFCI breakers?

Comment: @Jtl -- for GFCI breakers, it's because it simply can't be done that way.  Open neutral detection requires the contacts to be normally-open and held closed by power, but that would cause misbehavior under certain circumstances (if the GFCI breaker was tripping on overload in a series combination rating system, with the upstream breaker assisting in breaking the load, for instance -- the resulting automatic reclose of the GFCI breaker when the upstream breaker is reset would be surprising at least, and could violate UL489, even)

Comment: Is it available in permanent receptacles (not plugged in)? What receptacles have this feature? If none, why none?

Comment: @Jtl -- generally not, as an open neutral in permanent wiring generally will get hunted down and fixed promptly due to its impact on the circuit.  Cord-and-plug connected environments have to deal with way more abuse (such as intermittent plugs and whatnot)

Comment: Please see Ed Beal reply above. He has one. Also what other products can detect open neutral besides these?

Comment: @Jtl -- I saw his reply -- when he's saying "portable power station", he's talking about a cord-and-plug connected product (something like a GFCI-protected power strip)

Comment: But how about the RCD in Europe. Is it possible it can open when power gone? This is because I saw this discussion of open neutral service detector in a Thai discussion forum and they discussed about normal RCD opening when source neutral was loss. See: https://www.thaivisa.com/forum/topic/457002-the-hazard-of-an-open-circuit-neutral/ and graphics at https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/1024x768q90/924/sgzXRB.jpg

Comment: @Jtl -- European RCDs vary in this ability I suspect, although I have not seen one that *guarantees* in its specifications that it can trip despite an open neutral.

Comment: Ok. Last question. Do you believe that single phase European RCD has neutral (and it can detect it) in one of the leg so you can't use it on the US black and red 240v which are both hot?

Comment: @Jtl -- an European 1P+N RCD would get rather confused (and express its confusion by tripping) on any circuit that's not strictly 240V only.

Comment: I'm doing some reading now. But won't European RCD work in US 240v red and black wire since its only looking for unbalance, it does not care that both legs are live vs one live and one grounded.

Comment: @Jtl -- it could work, but the trip thresholds aren't quite right, and the *listing* will be wrong too (there are RCCBs that are UL certified, but they follow the UL 1053 standard for distribution-type ground-fault sensing/relaying equipment vs. a normal GFCI which follows the UL 943 standard for personnel protection GFCIs)

Comment: I'm looking for a 125A RCBO (Residual Current Circuit Breaker with Overcurrent) breaker with 100mA trip threshold to be put in subpanel with red and black 240v US power source. So if I use a European 125A RCBO with 100mA tripping. What do you mean the trip threshold not quite right.  It would still be 100mA, no? Or it would become just 50mA? How come? Many thanks.

Comment: @Jtl -- no, the trip threshold won't be right for the application.  The biggest issue will be the *listing* though....

Comment: @Jtl -- *why* do you want this, by the way?

Comment: why is the reason the trip threshold is not right? It's still all 230v (or 240v) so when the RCD has 100mA tripping threshold. Why won't it work in similar US 240v? Is the neutral got anything to do with it? But since the circuit only sense inbalance,, why won't the trip threshold be the same, any reference so I can look it up?  I just an open neutral disconnector to be used as main breaker in my subpanel.

Comment: @Jtl -- whenever the Code wants GFCI protection anywhere, it *always* wants UL943 Class A (6mA) protection unless it explicitly calls something else out.

Comment: And why are you so deathly concerned about losing a feeder neutral? Is this feeder run using a cable or wires in conduit?

Comment: In my condo, the neutral sometimes disconnects from bad building service. In there any US products based on UL 1053 whereby it can be used as main breaker in sub panel based (just to disconnect the panel from open neutral) based on your description "RCCBs that are UL certified, but they follow the UL 1053 standard for distribution-type ground-fault sensing/relaying" equipment". Don't worry. There are standard 5mA GFCI receptacles throughout the house.

Comment: @Jtl -- it sounds like your condo association needs to get bludgeoned over the head with a torque wrench until they fix the feeder neutrals, given the fire hazard dodgy neutrals pose.